# Using Pydantic settings config with multiple YAML files

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pydantic

I am looking at using pydantic_settings_yaml to load YAML config files in to a Pydantic model. Ideally, I would have a global.yml containing environment agnostic configuration and then an env.yml for environment specific configuration. It is not clear how pydantic_settings_yaml can handle this. I would like to avoid creating a merged.yml every time the config is loaded.

The below code will read dev.yml or live.yml in to the Pydantic model but not global.yml.

**app_config.py**

```
env = os.getenv("ENVIRONMENT", "").lower()

match env:
    case "dev":
        yaml_filename = "dev.yml"
        secrets_sub_dir = "dev"
    case "live":
        yaml_filename = "live.yml"
        secrets_sub_dir = "live"
    case _:
        raise Exception(f"Unrecognised environment: {env}")


class Settings(YamlBaseSettings):
    test_api_one: Dict[str, str]

    class Config:
        secrets_dir = f"/secrets/{secrets_sub_dir}"
        yaml_file = Path(__file__).parent / yaml_filename


config = Settings()
```

**dev.yml**

```
'test_api_one':
  'uri': 'https://dev_api/'
  'secret': <file:dev_secret>
```

**live.yml**

```
'test_api_one':
  'uri': 'https://live_api/'
  'secret': <file:live_secret>
```

**global.yml**

```
'test_api_one':
  'dateFormat': '%Y-%m-%d'
  'dateTimeFormat': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

Comment: Can you please link the repository of this third-party package? I could not find it.

Comment: Had assumed this was broadly used but also cannot find the source and it is v0.1. https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-settings-yaml/0.1.1/

Will rethink. Thanks.

Comment: I found the pypi page myself, which is why I asked for the source. I wonder how you came to assume this... Judging from the fact that the last version is 0.1.1, the last update on pypi was in Aug. last year and that there is no link to the actual source code, I would come to the opposite conclusion. Either way, writing your own settings callable for (vanilla) Pydantic `BaseSettings` that parses yaml is pretty easy. See: https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/settings/#customise-settings-sources

Comment: Link above is broken since pydantic and pydantic-settings split.
Updated link to how to customize pydantic settings sources: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#customise-settings-sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I have my doubts about the package you mentioned (see my comment above), I would propose implementing this yourself.

The Pydantic docs explain how you can [customize the settings sources](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/settings/#customise-settings-sources). To make sure nested dictionaries are updated "porperly", you can also use the very handy `pydantic.utils.deep_update` function.

Obviously, you'll need to install `pyyaml` for this to work.

Here is an example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseSettings as PydanticBaseSettings
from pydantic.env_settings import SettingsSourceCallable
from pydantic.utils import deep_update
from yaml import safe_load


THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent


class BaseSettings(PydanticBaseSettings):
    test_api_one: dict[str, str]

    class Config:
        config_files = [
            Path(THIS_DIR, "global.yaml"),
            Path(THIS_DIR, "dev.yaml"),
        ]

        @classmethod
        def customise_sources(
                cls,
                init_settings: SettingsSourceCallable,
                env_settings: SettingsSourceCallable,
                file_secret_settings: SettingsSourceCallable
        ) -> tuple[SettingsSourceCallable, ...]:
            return init_settings, env_settings, config_file_settings


def config_file_settings(settings: PydanticBaseSettings) -> dict[str, Any]:
    config: dict[str, Any] = {}
    if not isinstance(settings, BaseSettings):
        return config
    for path in settings.Config.config_files:
        if not path.is_file():
            print(f"No file found at `{path.resolve()}`")
            continue
        print(f"Reading config file `{path.resolve()}`")
        if path.suffix in {".yaml", ".yml"}:
            config = deep_update(config, load_yaml(path))
        else:
            print(f"Unknown config file extension `{path.suffix}`")
    return config


def load_yaml(path: Path) -> dict[str, Any]:
    with Path(path).open("r") as f:
        config = safe_load(f)
    if not isinstance(config, dict):
        raise TypeError(
            f"Config file has no top-level mapping: {path}"
        )
    return config
```

Now assuming these are the files in question:

`global.yaml`

```yaml
test_api_one:
  date_format: '%Y-%m-%d'
  date_time_format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

`dev.yaml`

```yaml
test_api_one:
  uri: 'https://dev_api/'
  secret: dev
```

The ouput of doing `print(BaseSettings().json(indent=4))` is this:

```
Reading config file `.../global.yaml`
Reading config file `.../dev.yaml`
```

```json
{
    "test_api_one": {
        "date_format": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "date_time_format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",
        "uri": "https://dev_api/",
        "secret": "dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: deep_update function v useful, thanks

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be for Pydantic settings 2.  3 completely changed the approach (and, frankly, it's incredibly difficult to follow the new approach).

Answer (score 0):

fajnberg thankyou for your answer. I did try to follow your advice and I think the code may be outdated.

At the end I did go with a simpler solution:

```
class Settings(BaseModel):
    field: str = "sqlite:///./unset.db"

    @staticmethod
    def load() -> "Settings":
        config_data:dict = {}
        for path in ["path1","path2"]:
            with open(path, "r") as yaml_file:
               config_data.update(yaml.safe_load(yaml_file))
        return sSettings(**config_data)
```

Then I just read settings in a single place with

```
settings = Settings.load()
```